# /startup endpoint not present in native app (using cnb and BufferingApplicationStartup)

Tags: spring-boot, startup, spring-boot-actuator, spring-native

Following the guidance [here in the Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.spring-application.startup-tracking) and having Actuator in the deps + this in main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Thing2Application.class);
    app.setApplicationStartup(new BufferingApplicationStartup(2048));
    app.run(args);
}
```

The /actuator/startup endpoint is present and populated when running as a standard, JVM-based (WebFlux/RSocket) app, but not when using buildpacks to create a native image. It simply doesn't appear, no indications present.

Is /startup not yet available when creating native Boot apps? If it is, please advise of any additional steps I may have missed exposing it. If not, please let me know and I'll log a request. Thanks!

Comment: This endpoint is not enabled by default in all environments. Did you enable it with the configuration property ˋmanagement.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=trueˋ ?

Comment: Hi Brian! That isn't documented anywhere I can find in the docs link above (or anywhere else I can find), but I did give it a try. Still no startup endpoint when running as a native app. :/

Comment: You must have more than what you've described for the endpoint to work in JVM mode. Re "It isn't documented anywhere": https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/26978. Actuator is fairly limited still with Native. Feel free to create an issue and please attach a sample project.

Comment: Hi Stephane, great to hear from you too! I really don't have more in there than described...the only props in application.properties are server.port, spring.rsocket.server.port, and management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=* (for demo purposes only, of course). Other than the deps for WebFlux & RSocket, it's a very basic project.

I'll open an issue and provide a link to a repo. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Just noticed your other point (sheepish grin). @stephane, I still don't see anywhere in any of the links within the one you shared a reference to the property Brian pointed out,  ˋmanagement.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=trueˋ. That's what I meant when I said "That isn't documented anywhere I can find in the docs link above..."

Irrelevant since it didn't affect the outcome, but if a property is required to enable a feature, wouldn't it make sense to include that in the docs?

Thanks!

Comment: My bad, for some reason I read "liveness" in your question - so please disregard my first comment as it was out of scope. At this point, I think that a sample application showing the issue here would help https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-native/issues Thanks!

Comment: Hi @BrianClozel, no worries, and thank you for closing the loop on this & getting the issue where it needs to be for resolution.

Just to keep everything in sync for anyone searching SO for similar issues, here is the repo I submitted demonstrating the logged behavior: https://github.com/mkheck/spring-boot-actuator-startupendpoint-nativecode-issue

Here is the issue I filed originally for Actuator: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/27004

And here is the Spring Native issue: https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-native/issues/851

Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That is a Spring Native bug that is being tracked [in this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-native/issues/851).